# Understand stack recursive in java

Tags: java, recursion

The code works well. It's just i don't get it. Having difficult in the recursive part. In this part: `char a = st.peek();st.pop(); insert_at_bottom(x); st.push(a);` my idea is that first it will execute `char a = st.peek();st.pop()` all the time until a threshold. then it will execute `st.push(a);` one time. So the `a` will only be assigned value once. Obviously that is not true.

The difficult part for me is in the `insert_at_bottom` method what does `insert_at_bottom(x)` do? in  `reverse` method what does `reverse()`, `insert_at_bottom(x)`do?

```
import java.util.Stack;
class Test {
    static Stack<Character> st = new Stack<>();
    static void insert_at_bottom(char x)
    {
        if(st.isEmpty()) st.push(x);
        else
        {char a = st.peek();
            st.pop();
            insert_at_bottom(x);
            st.push(a);
        }
    }
    
    static void reverse()
    {
        if(st.size() > 0)
        {           
            char x = st.peek();
            st.pop();
            reverse();
            insert_at_bottom(x);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   st.push('1'); st.push('2'); st.push('3'); st.push('4');     
        System.out.println("Original Stack");
        System.out.println(st);
        reverse();
        System.out.println("Reversed Stack");
        System.out.println(st); }}
```

Comment: Incidentally, instead of using `st.size() > 0`, you should probably use `!st.isEmpty()`. Depending on the implementation of `Stack`, finding the size of the stack can be much slower than checking whether it's empty. And there's no way that checking the size can be appreciably slower than checking emptiness.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, we will use `[]` notation for stacks. An empty stack will be denoted `[]`. When we push or pop an element, we will do so on the left side. For example, if we start with `[1, 2, 3]` and pop, we will be left with `[2, 3]` and the pop will return `1`. And if we start with `[1, 2, 3]` and push `0`, we will be left with `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.

`insert_at_bottom`'s sole purpose is enabling us to push append an element to the *right* side of the stack, rather than the *left* side of the stack.

So how do we insert something (let's say we want to insert `x`) on the right side of the stack rather than the left side? We consider two different cases:

1. The stack is empty: that is, `st = []`.

In this case, pushing to the right and pushing to the left are the same thing, so we just call `st.push(x)` and now have `st = [x]`.

2. The stack is non-empty: for example, the stack is ['1', '2', '3'].

First, we pop `'1'` off the stack. Now we have `st = ['2', '3']`.
Then, we push x onto the right side of `st` by making a recursive call. This gives us `st = ['2', '3', x]`.
Finally, we push `'1'` back onto the stack. This gives us `st = ['1', '2', '3', x]`. As you can see, we have successfully inserted `x` at the rightmost position of `st`.

This is how `insert_at_bottom` works.

Now how does `reverse` work? We again consider two distinct cases.

1. The stack is empty; that is, `st = []`.

In this case, we don't need to do anything to reverse `st`.

2. The stack is non-empty; we will take `st = ['1', '2', '3']` as our example.

First, we pop `'1'` from the stack, leaving us with `st = ['2', '3']`.
Then, we reverse `st`, leaving us with `st = ['3', '2']`.
Finally, we insert `'1'` at the right side of `st` by calling `insert_bottom('1')`, leaving us with `st = ['3', '2', '1']`.

As you can see, we have successfully reversed `st`.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what your methods do, you have to understand what a `Stack` is. A `Stack` is like a stack of plates: you can only put plates on the top of the stack, or retrieve plates from the top. Otherwise, the stack will collapse.

If you want to add a plate at the bottom of the plate, you have to remove all the plates before. The easy way is to do as following: while there is a plate on the stack, you remove it and put it aside. If the stack is empty, then you can put your new plate at the bottom of the stack. Then you have to put back all the plates on the newly-bottom plate.

That the exact same operation here in `insert_at_bottom` but with a recursive method: while you have a `char` in your stack - i.e. it is not empty -, you put the top `char` - which is labelled as `a` - aside and you try again to put `x` to the bottom. If the stack is not empty, you re-do the operation. Once you have hit the bottom of your stack, you can put `x` there and start pushing all the other `char`s in the same order they were before.

The `reverse` method uses almost the same process with a little twist: you take the top `char`, put is aside, take the second-top `char`, put it aside, ... When you're on the last `char`, you can put it at the bottom of the stack. Then you put the previously-second-bottom `char` at the bottom of the stack... And you go back to the previously-top `char` that you put to the final bottom. All your stack has then been reversed.

Comment: https://afteracademy.com/blog/reverse-a-stack-using-recursion This link seems very good. Like the commentor said:  tried to understand the code but just can't understand it. " Can you guide me by simple step by step of the stack [1,2]